# My Vuetify Nuxt SSR (Universal) application on Firebase is hanging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Update: My approach to use 2 folders: functions and src in not working. I started to use another approach when folder for firebase functions is located inside of the src folder. This approach is implemented by **winzaa123** user: [winzaa123/nuxt2-vuetify-ssr-on-firebase](https://github.com/winzaa123/nuxt2-vuetify-ssr-on-firebase) and I could launch it on my Google firebase.

### My Steps: Preparation of the project from scratch

#### Create a Nuxt app inside of the src folder:

1. Create a Nuxt app in ***src*** folder with `create-nuxt-app src`
2. Choose the package manager Npm
3. Choose UI framework Vuetify.js
4. Choose rendering mode Universal (SSR)

#### Create a Firebase Project

5. Create a Firebase project with `firebase init`
6. Select Firebase Hosting, Firebase Functions, Firebase Firestore, Firebase Storage, Emulators
7. Use public directory? (public)
8. Configure as a single-page app (y/N) - Yes

#### Create a package.json file in the root folder

```
{
  "name": "test-nuxt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My fine Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "Alex Pilugin",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd functions && npm install",
    "dev": "cd src && npm run dev",
    "start": "cd src && npm run dev",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=development firebase serve",
    "build": "cd src && npm run build",
    "build-deploy": "firebase deploy --only hosting,functions",
    "build-deployf": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "build-deployh": "firebase deploy --only hosting"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

[image: Project Folder Structure]

### Edit firebase.json file

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "rm -rf functions/nuxt && npm --prefix src run build && mkdir -p functions/nuxt/dist && cp -r src/.nuxt/dist/ functions/nuxt/dist && cp src/nuxt.config.js functions/"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "predeploy": [
      "rm -rf public/* && mkdir -p public/_nuxt/ && cp -r functions/nuxt/dist/client/ public/_nuxt/ && cp -a src/static/. public/"
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nuxtssr"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

You can see that I plan to copy content of the ***src/.nuxt/dist/client*** into the ***public/_nuxt*** folder.
I am doing it since I found `"publicPath": "/_nuxt/"` inside of the ***src/.nuxt/dist/server/client.manifest.json***

### Nest Step is editing of the functions/index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const { Nuxt } = require("nuxt");
//const { Nuxt } = require("nuxt-start");

const config = {
  ssrLog: true,
  dev: true, // Don't start in dev mode.
  debug: true, //<----------------------- Debug logs
  buildDir: "nuxt",
  build: {
    //publicPath: ''
    //publicPath: '/_nuxt/',   //Default: '/_nuxt/' <-- content of .nuxt/dist/client
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend ( config, { isDev, isClient, isServer } ) {
      if ( isServer ) {
        config.externals = {
          '@firebase/app': 'commonjs @firebase/app',
          '@firebase/firestore': 'commonjs @firebase/firestore',
          //etc...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

let isReady = false;

async function handleRequest(req, res) {
  console.log("nuxtssr is running...");

  if (!isReady) {
    console.log("isReady: " + isReady);
    try {
      console.log("waiting for nuxt.ready().......");
      isReady = await nuxt.ready();
      console.log("nuxt is ready");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERROR.....................");
      console.log(error);
      //throw new functions.https.HttpsError('error in Nuxt', error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
  console.log("waiting for nuxt.render().......");

  /*
  * res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=1, s-maxage=1');
  * await nuxt.render(req, res);
  */

  res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("before nuxt.render......");
    nuxt.render(req, res, promise => {
      console.log("inside nuxt.render......");
      promise.then(resolve).catch(reject);
    });
  });
}

exports.nuxtssr = functions.https.onRequest(handleRequest);
```

I use `$ npm start` to launch the application locally:

```
Nuxt.js v2.12.2                           
Running in development mode (universal)   
Listening on: http://localhost:3000/
```

I deploy the application using `$ firebase deploy` command but I cannot see any Frontend. My application is hanging.
[image: nuxtssr is hanging]

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, firebase hosting is *only* for static files. If you're trying to do SSR, that implies that there's a server running and some processing happening on the server side. You may need to deploy this to Google Cloud Functions as a "serverless" app. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/likecoin/quick-nuxt-js-ssr-prototyping-with-firebase-cloud-functions-5277553610a8) for an example.

That said, I'm not super familiar with Nuxt, but I can see two things you potentially need to do differently if you are, indeed, deploying to the correct place.

First, the `hosting.public` property in `firebase.json` should be the path to the folder that contains your built project. Since you've said your project is being built in `public/_nuxt`, you might need to change this property to match, i.e. in `firebase.json` have

```js
{
  ...
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public/_nuxt",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

For what it's worth, in regular (i.e. non-Nuxt) Vue projects, the project gets built in the `dist/` folder, so in my `firebase.json` file I have `"public": "dist"`. That said, I haven't ever hosted a Nuxt SSR project on firebase so this may not be how it is structured.

Second, you likely need to run `nuxt build` or `nuxt generate` *before* you run `firebase deploy` so that the project is built to the target directory. The `firebase deploy` command really is just a fancy way to upload files onto Google's platform.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. And there is "predeploy" command in "functions" which contains "npm --prefix src run build" command - it means I run "nuxt build" before "firebase deploy"